# How to use the PM2 instance that's already running

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to use [`PM2`](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2) process manager. I'm installing it with ansible and the [franklinkim.pm2 role](https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-pm2)

It works, it launches my node app and if I manually kill the node app I see that PM2 relaunches it

But..., I can seem to access the existing PM2 instance.

If type `ps aux | grep PM2` I get

```
root      1073  4.1  8.3 648348 41736 ?        Ssl  06:12   0:00 PM2 v0.12.15: God Daemon
```

now I want to see PM2's list of processes so I type `sudo pm2 list` and I get

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

Fail! Instead of showing me the running PM2 it spawned a new one

i've tried `sudo -u root pm2 list` and just `pm2 list` but I get the same results or if the second one is already running I only see the list from the second instance, not the one running my app.

I feel like whatever the reason it it's some fundamental misunderstanding of users and processes on linux I don't yet grok.

Comment: Can you try `sudo -i pm2 list`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*pm2* will use `$HOME` variable to determine where is `.pm2` directory resided. Of course you can [override it with](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/604#issuecomment-62819216) `$PM2_HOME` variable

When you invoked pm2 with ansible, looks like you've use root user. So, `.pm2` directory located in `/root/.pm2`. So, the solution is using command

```
sudo -i pm2 list
```

When you invoke `sudo` without `-i` parameter, all environment variable (including `$HOME`) will still inherited from original account before sudo.

Comment: In case it helps someone else, my pm2 process was not running at $HOME, and `PM2_HOME=/etc/.pm2 sudo -i pm2 list` did not work for me, but `sudo -i PM2_HOME=/etc/.pm2 pm2 list` did.

Comment: This is fantastic. I never knew that sudo had flags. This answer was very hard to find, but so worth it in the end.